# How to add class to HTML elements through input fields in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a gallery where you can upload images with a category. This category needs to be added as a class so that I can sort it out. Or are there other ways to categorise images in a gallery without using class

Comment: can you post the code that you've tried.

Comment: Do you mean CSS class? The would be useful if you wanted to style based on the category but if you simply want to places images in categories then save the value provided by the user into the database and it becomes a filter that you query on.

Comment: how about using data-*.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have to use javascript.

A quick and rough example would be:

```
var className = document.getElementById("InputField");
element.classList.add(className);
```

Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Thanks. I have used another way to categorise the images.

Answer (score 0):

Using `jQuery` and `bootsrap`

```js
$('#needs-border').addClass('border border-info');
$('p').addClass('border border-danger');

//using input
$(document).on('change' , 'select', function(){
  var color = $(this).val();
  var bgDiv = $('#bg');
  bgDiv.removeClass('bg-info bg-success bg-danger');
  if(color){
    bgDiv.addClass(color)
  }

})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="bg" class="row p-3">
  <div id="needs-border" class="col-md-12 m-4 p-3">
    <p class="m-1">This is a paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row p-3">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <select class="form-control">
       <option value="">Remove all</option>
       <option value="bg-danger">Red</option>
       <option value="bg-info">Blue</option>
       <option value="bg-success">green</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```